# Merge RDD of (key,id) with RDD of (k1,k2)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have an original RDD with data that looks kind of like:

```
(A,A)
(A,B)
(B,C)
(C,D)
```

These are edges in a graph (represented as vertex names.) I use some code to generate a second RDD with unique ids.

```
 (A,0)
 (B,41)
 (C,82)
 (D,123)
```

I want to somehow merge these RDDs to get a final RDD that looks like:

```
Edge(0,0,AA)
Edge(0,41,AB)
Edge(41,82,BC)
Edge(82,123,CD)
```

Basically creating an Edge[RDD] so that I can use graphx on these edges. Is it possible to merge the Id RDD with the original edge RDD?

Comment: Any of the below helpful?

Comment: @mtoto I had to rewrite a bunch of backend code so I haven't been able to test. I think @semsorock might have a good solution. I'm thinking of using pure RDDs now and using `join` to get everything paired how I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
val df1 = rdd1.toDF("col1", "col2")
val df2 = rdd2.toDF("col", "val")

df1.join(df2, $"col1" === $"col").drop(col("col")).join(df2, $"col2" === $"col").drop(col("col")).show

+----+----+---+---+
|col1|col2|val|val|
+----+----+---+---+
|   A|   B|  0| 41|
|   C|   D| 82|123|
|   B|   C| 41| 82|
|   A|   A|  0|  0|
+----+----+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

If your id `rdd` is not too big, you could broadcast it create your edge `rdd`:

```scala
// Create broadcast variable from id _rdd
val bc_lookup = sc.broadcast(rdd_id.collectAsMap())

// Create lookup function that returns intermediate rdd
def lookup_custom(x: (String, String)): (Int,Int,String) = {
   (bc_lookup.value.get(x._1).get, 
    bc_lookup.value.get(x._2).get,
    x._1 + x._2)
}

val rdd_result = my_rdd.map(x => lookup_custom(x)).cache()

// Convert to Edge RDD
val e_rdd = rdd_result.map(x => Edge(x._1, x._2, x._3))

e_rdd.collect()
// res1: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[String]] = Array(Edge(0,0,AA), Edge(0,41,AB), Edge(41,82,BC), Edge(82,123,CD))
```

**Data**

```
val my_rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("A","A"),("A","B"),("B","C"),("C", "D")))
val rdd_id = sc.parallelize(Seq(("A",0),("B",41),("C",82),("D",123)))
```